# How to enable shortcodes in text retrieved from get_theme_mod

Tags: shortcode, theme-customizer

Is there a way to enable shortcodes in text saved in the customizer and retrieved using get_theme_mod?

I'm guessing there's a filter in a similar manner to enabling shortcodes in widgets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To enable shortcodes in text widgets add a filter like that:

```
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode' );
```

You can pass every string to `do_shortcode()` including `get_theme_mod()` calls.

```
echo do_shortcode( get_theme_mod( 'theme_setting' ) );
```

Comment: Sorry, to clarify I have a textarea input in the customizer which stores some "about us" text. I'd like to give the user the ability to use shortcodes in this text which, when echoed in the template, would process the shortcode.

Comment: The second snippet will do what you need - just replace `theme_setting` with the name of your "about us" text setting.

Comment: Yes, that should work. You wrote you use `get_theme_mod()`, that's why I gave you that example.